# How and where can I interpret a Java error message of "3" returned from java.lang.String?

Tags: java, exception, runtime-error

I am running a Java program that parses `BufferedReader` input into a delimited string for output to a file. After successfully reading 24 lines from the source file and saving them to the destination file, I get an error message of `3` (using the `getMessage()`) method in the `catch` paired with the "read the next line of the file" `try`.

When I change the catch to the following,

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage().getClass().getName());
    }
```

the `catch` results in the `Error: java.lang.String` being returned...but no further explanation. Bad characters in the file? Inorrect casting? OutOfBounds as another comment suggested? any other ideas how to extract further information from this error?

I have reviewed the input file in a hex editor and there are no unexpected EOF or null characters between the rows, the input data displays as expected in a hex or text editor, and I cannot find any documentation about how to interpret a `3` error message, or even how to determine if it's an OS or Java exception.

Comment: I've never heard of java giving exceptions that unhelpful, are you using any libraries

Comment: Add in `e.getClass().getName()` to the string printed so you know what type of error it is. That should give you more info.

Comment: It's likely that an array index out of bound exception is thrown with the index being 3??

Comment: @RichardTingle: `import java.util.*;`, `import java.io.*;`, `import java.nio.file.*;`, `import java.util.regex.*;`, `import java.lang.StringBuilder;`

Comment: @srkavin - I'll check my arrays, but the one I've tested already (and that prints fine to the console when not writing to a file) contains 5 elements.

Comment: The proper way is to use e.printStackTrace(). Anything else is ridiculous and won't give you enough information.

Comment: @srkavin - Looks like a bad array...got the error message nailed down in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `e.getMessage()`, try using `e.printStackTrace()`.  This will show the full details of the exception and should point you in the right direction.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.err.print("Error: ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can also try:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.err.println("Error: " + e);
}
```

Comment: `printStackTrace()` method is void type one, so you code will not even compile

Comment: The latter version is not good, since it'll just show the message (which is usually useless).

Comment: I just threw all of these in my catch. :)  ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: 3, and even a line number for the code. Exactly what I needed.